Linux Shell Script replace last shown lines at the screen, not write it under the last once
i run a script from bring formated numbers to the screen :
#!/bin/sh

while true ; do
    echo
    awk -v x=987654321 -v n=8 'BEGIN{srand(); while (--n) {$++NF = int(rand() * x / n); x -= $NF}; $++NF = x; print}' > numbers_in_one_line

    cat numbers_in_one_line |
                     tr " " "\n" |
                             rev |
         sed -E "s/(...)/\\1./g" |
                  sed "s/\.$//g" |
                             rev | xargs printf '| %15s  |\n'  > numbers_line_by_line_right_dots

    cat numbers_line_by_line_right_dots
    echo
    printf 'ok? (y/n)? '
    read answer
    if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ] ;then
        echo Yes

        read -a numbers < numbers_in_one_line
        j=0
        for i in "${numbers[@]}"; do
        echo > ok.txt
        done

        exit 0
    else
        echo No
    fi
done
echo

the loop is only ending by press y (or CTRL C), all other keys starts the loop again and again.
by press any key, not y, the new lines comes under the old lines at the screen, looks not so got, but is there a way if the loop starts new, to replace the last lines with the new ones at the screen?

If you can programmatically determine where you should start, you could echo out ANSI CTRL SEQUENCES
For example you could echo the number of backspaces per line and echo up after each line. Or depending on the application you could just run the shell command clear.
